# No mysql connection on heroku deployment - Laravel 5.2

Tags: mysql, heroku, deployment, laravel-5

So I was experimenting with my application and I decided to deploy it to heroku, in order to see how it reacts in real time and to show it to other people. 
Well the deployment succeeded but I get this error:

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory

The application is on PHP-Laravel 5.2.

*Just so to be clear, on my machine it works just fine, meaning on localhost.

I have also installed cleardb addon on heroku. I tried to run `heroku run php artisan refresh --seed` but the same error as before appeared. If anyone can help, I would really appreciate it!

Comment: Have your seed completed and Is your .env file ok ?

Comment: No, as I said before, I can't seed. I get the same error when I try it.